# How to ping roles discord.js@14.6.0

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, i tried to ping roles in Discord.js 14 in an embed, but it doesn't work. It only shows `<@&1032648819340480586>` this and not the actual role itself.

I hope I can get help here.

Comment: Hi welcome! Could you please [edit] your post by adding a [mcve]? :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try typing `<@&1032648819340480586>` in the server with that role and check if it replaces it with the actual role's ping. If not, then you got the wrong ID. Also, you can't really ping roles in embeds, it'll show it as a ping but not ping members with the role.

Answer (score 0):

Eh! I have figured it, discord.js@14 doesnt allow to ping in the :
footer
title
thumbnail
description
I just put it in the fields and it worked